# How to Insert color into the data table (td)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

```
<script>
function data_table(){
 $("#table_test").DataTable({
 bDestroy: true, processing: true,
 ajax: {type: "POST",url: "file",data: {date:date},
 dataSrc: function (data) {
            var return_data = new Array();
            $(data).each(function(key, value ) {
                return_data.push({
                    "name": value.name ,"col1": value.col1 ,"col2": value.col2 ,"col3": value.col3 ,
                    "col4": value.col4 ,"col5": value.col5
                });
            });
            return return_data;
    }// End dataSrc
  },"columns" : [
    {"data": "name"},{"data": "col1"},{"data": "col2"},
    {"data": "col3"},{"data": "col4"},{"data": "col5"}
]
 });
}
</script>
```

[image]

W = color white

BL = color black

R = color red

B = color blue

From the picture

> test1 -> column1 value W,column2 value W,column3 value W column4 value
>   BL and column5 value R
>
> test2 -> column1 value BL,column2 value B,column3 value B column4
>   value B and column5 value B

I want to add a different background color to a column in alphabetical order.

sample: test1 column5 value R put the column background color in red (td).

Comment: What have you tried? PHP doesn't seem to be related. `style="background:#000;"` maybe is a starting point for you

Comment: I want to add color $(td).css("background-color","color");
but I'm can not add in td

Comment: The `td` should be in quotes and you need to target the specific cell. Do you have an id or class on the elements?